# How to create a big matrix like with 1000 rows & columns in c?

Tags: c, matrix, random, graph

I wrote a simple code to create a Directed Graph using adjacency matrix with randomly generated numbers that are the vertices of the graph. But my task is to make a bigger matrix with 1000 rows and columns. My code cannot make more than a 50*50 matrix. How can I make a big matrix?

This is the code that I have created.

```
int arr[1001][1001];
int main()
{
int i,a,b,j,k,m,n;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
for(i=0;i<b;i++)
{
    m=rand()%100;
    n=rand()%100;
    arr[m-1][n-1]=1;
}
for(j=0;j<a;j++)
{
    for(k=0;k<a;k++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[j][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The compiler doesn't give any output.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: It is possible that your stack size is limited. Try allocating this array on heap through malloc.

Comment: It's GNU CCC Compiler built in the CodeBlocks software.

Comment: How can I use malloc?

Comment: I used m-1 and n-1 for making a directed graph

Comment: I cannot see any graph in this code.

Comment: I have posted code which allocates on heap, but you should read up on [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) itself to familiarize yourself with dynamic memory allocations, its implications and uses.

Comment: there is no graph exactly. I just wanted to create matrix.

Comment: `m-1` is not correct! `m=rand()%100` may result 0 then m would be -1.

Comment: Thanks for the complement. But, that's not my issue.

Comment: You have your solutions in the answers!

Comment: Thanks Jo, It's solved

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a flat array like this:

```
#define MATR(arr, column, row) (arr + column + row*101)

int* arr = (int*)malloc(101*101*sizeof(int));

*MATR(arr, 1, 2) = 123;
```

Then you only need one malloc/free.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I propose you doesn't use an array of pointers to pointer, it uses only a vector managed as an array by means some `#define`. In this way the code will be generated might be faster.

With the vector solution you will need to free only a vector, with the solution with pointers to pointer you will need to free all columns pointers and then the "rows" pointer.

Into the code I've set to 1 only the array elements comprised in the interval you set with the variable `a`, otherwise the output might show only elements containing 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 1000
#define COLS 1000

#define ARRAY(m,n) [n+m*COLS]

int main()
{
    int i,a,b,j,k,m,n;

    int * arr = malloc(COLS*ROWS*sizeof(*arr));

    if (arr) {
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

        for(i=0;i<b;i++)
        {
            // m=rand()%ROWS; // to set into the full array
            m=rand()%a;
            // m=i; to have a diagonal
            // n=rand()%COLS; // to set into the full array
            n=rand()%a;
            // n=i; to have a diagonal
            arr ARRAY(m,n)=1;
        }

        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<a;k++)
            {
                printf("%d ",arr ARRAY(j,k));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        free(arr);
    } else {
        perror("malloc: ");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- C uses, as first element of arrays, the indexes couple (0,0) not (1,1).
- The instruction `m=rand()%x` generates numbers from 0 to x-1.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are only printing an `a*a` matrix.
2. As previously seen you will need dynamic memory allocation.
3. So, you can allocate an `a*a` matrix and do not need to allocate the `1001 * 1001` matrix.
4. The setting of `1's` has been modified to stop out of bounds error and index of `-1`
5. Memory allocation call of `calloc` is used to initialze the matrix to zero.

Modified code is below.

```
int main(void)
{
    int **arr;    
    int i,a,b,j,k,m,n;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    arr = malloc (sizeof(int*) * a);
    for (i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = calloc(a,sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        m=rand()%a;
        n=rand()%a;
        arr[m][n]=1;
    }
    for(j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<a;k++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare your array like this: `int arr[1001][1001];` This is perfectly fine as long as you don't put it on the stack. Since you declare it globaly, everything should be OK.

But the way you *use* the array is not OK:

```
m=rand()%100;
n=rand()%100;
arr[m-1][n-1]=1;
```

Here `m` and `n` will have values in the range `0...99`. When both `m` and `n` are zero, your array asignement will turn into this:

```
arr[-1][-1]=1;
```

And you will get undefined behaviour.

Probably (depending on your use case), the asignement should look like this

```
arr[m][n] = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

For a heap based array, see below.

```
int main()
{
    int i,a,b,j,k,m,n;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    int** arr = (int**)malloc(1001*sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<1001;++i)
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(1001*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        m=rand()%100;
        n=rand()%100;
        arr[m-1][n-1]=1;
    }
    for(j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<a;k++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[j][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // memory not freed since the program is ending anyway. In real programs, use free to free the 102 arrays.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code clearing the uses of malloc. But, your code is not working to make a big matrix. It creates not more than 60*60 matrix.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your system/compiler then. This code is supposed to create 1001 arrays of arrays of int on heap, which it will.

Comment: I am using GNU CCC Compiler

Comment: You cannot use m-1 and n-1 as indexes. The instruction rand()%x returns numbers between 0 and x-1, thus you could have negative indexes.